# alert box in PHP and navigation to another page

Tags: javascript, php

I am using javascript to check whether username and password are not empty. If one of these is empty, javascript alert is displayed and PHP script should not work, that is username and password validation should not occur and login page should be displayed once again. Is there any simple code to do this?

Nobody need to build whole form. I have already build login form and PHP script for its validation, I just want to know is there any method or function in PHP to stop script on entering empty username/password and submitting

Comment: There is plenty. This is a fairly common task, you should be able to find it easily.

Comment: I am unable to do this. Suggest me a simple solution

Comment: Nobody is going to build a full login form for you here unless he is desperate for some rep.  Be specific about your problem, maybe add your code here for HTML, PHP and JS that you tried.

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr And doing that just spoils the OP for future questions.

Comment: Nobody need to build whole form. I have already build login form and wrote PHP for its validation, I just want to know is there any method or function in PHP to stop script on empty username/password

Comment: @GopalAggarwalare you saying that we should encourage these type of questions?  There is already lot of such full solutions available on web with demonstrations.  I guess that the purpose of SO is to make a better place where community answers the questions that are not "please give me the code".

Comment: Yes, while doing JavaScript/jQuery/etc validation, if it fails, in addition to alerting the user, `return false`, `e.preventDefault()` or similar to stop the form from submitting, thus, preventing PHP from executing.

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr No, actually I mean the complete opposite of what you understood. I mean, without OP proving his effort, if someone does the work for reputation points, it just spoils the OP's ideas that he can repeat this in future.

Comment: Kindly show your JavaScript, HTML code so that we can guide you better.

Comment: You are seriously discouraging me. I am beginner to PHP. It's not that every one knows every thing.

Comment: @NitishBangad nobody here is going to discourage you.  We just need to look at your code to identify and suggest corrections and any additional code that can do what you want.  Just edit the question and add your PHP and JS or whatever other code you already have.

Comment: @GopalAggarwal we are on same page now.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

Php Code :

```
 <p>
    <label for="first">User Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="First Name" id="first" />
 </p>
 <p>
     <label for="last">Password:</label>
     <input type="text" name="Last Name" id="last" />
 </p>

 <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="button2" value="Submit" onClick="javascript:verify()"/>
```

JavaScript Code :

```
function verify() {

   if (document.getElementById('first').value=="") {
      alert("Please Enter Your Name");
      return false;
   }
   else if (document.getElementById('last').value=="") {
      alert("Please Enter Your Password"); 
      return false;
   }
   else {
       document.form.submit();
   }

}
```

Working Model : http://jsfiddle.net/NWWL4/24/

Answer (score -1):

```
      It took me awhile to get this right. I have my form in my html index 
    page. On a closed question here, I read this couldn't be done.
    This php works VERY well with my form. 
    It generates a Javascript alert for good and bad results and 
    links back to the index page in either instance.
    If you look at the 2nd echo, you'll see where you can redirect to 
    another page. I just loaded same page to clear form.
    If you want to see the ccs, just ask.

    PHP:
                <?php
                if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                    $to = "admin@blahblah.com";
                    $name_field = $_POST['name'];
                    $email_field = $_POST['email'];
                    $subject_field = $_POST['subject'];
                    $message = $_POST['message'];
                    $body = "From: $name_field\n E-Mail: $email_field:\n Subject: $subject_field\n Message: $message\n";
                    }
                if(empty($name_field) || empty($email_field) || empty($subject_field) || empty($message)) {
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("There is a problem, please check the fields");window.history.go(-1);</script>';
                }
                else {
                if(mail($to, $subject_field, $body)) {
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Message successfully sent");window.location = "https://www.blahblah.com/";</script>';
                    }}
                exit;
                  ?>

    html:
               <div class="clear"></div>
             <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-3">
      <form role="form" action="php\mailer.php" method="post" id="form">  
              <div class="form-group">
                <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" maxlength="30">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input name="email" type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" maxlength="30">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input name="subject" type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" placeholder="Your Subject" maxlength="40">
              </div>
           <div><input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send Message"></input></div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-9">
             <div class="txtarea">
           <textarea name="message" rows="10" class="form-control" id="message"></textarea>
       </form>
          <div class="clear"></div>            
<div class="col-lg-12" style="text-align:center">           
<a class="btn btn-large btn-contact-link" href="#blahblah_home">Home</a>
```

Comment: Please review your formatting. Text should start without any indentation. Code blocks are indented with 4 spaces. You can use the `{}` button to indent code blocks.